# How to refactor LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following code:

```
result = from i in _dbContext.Meetings
         where i.UserInvitedID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && //!i.IsTex &&
         DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DbFunctions.AddHours(i.MeetingTime.Day, i.MeetingTime.Hour).Value, i.MeetingTime.Minute).Value > dateWithTime
         //where i.UserInvitedID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day) >= date
         select new ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp()
         {
             Name = i.UserInviter.FirstName + " " + i.UserInviter.LastName,
             Company = i.UserInviter.Company,
             Company2 = i.UserInvited.Company,
             MeetingID = i.MeetingID,
             Time = DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DbFunctions.AddHours(i.MeetingTime.Day, i.MeetingTime.Hour).Value, i.MeetingTime.Minute).Value,
             CreatedTime = i.dateCreated,
             Image = i.UserInviter.ProfileImage,
             TableNumber = i.TableNumber,
             Username = i.UserInviter.aspnet_User.UserName,
             Username2 = i.UserInvited.aspnet_User.UserName,
             UsernameInviter = i.UserInviter.aspnet_User.UserName,
             RequestText = i.RequestText,
             NoteInviter = i.NoteInviter,
             ResendInvitationCount = (i.ResendInvitationCount.HasValue) ? i.ResendInvitationCount.Value : 0,
             NoteInvited = i.NoteInvited,
             MeetingType = i.MeetingType.TypeName
         };
```

I use many such extentions with different modifications, but each of them has the same part `select new ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp()....`.

i.e.

```
result = from i in _dbContext.Meetings
         where i.UserInviterID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && !i.IsTex && DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DbFunctions.AddHours(i.MeetingTime.Day, i.MeetingTime.Hour).Value, i.MeetingTime.Minute).Value > dateWithTime
         //where i.UserInviterID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day) >= date
         select new ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp()
         {
             Name = i.UserInvited.FirstName + " " + i.UserInvited.LastName,
             //...
         };


result = from i in _dbContext.Meetings
         where (i.UserInviterID == CurrentUserID) && i.MeetingStatus == true && !i.IsTex && DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DbFunctions.AddHours(i.MeetingTime.Day, i.MeetingTime.Hour).Value, i.MeetingTime.Minute).Value > dateWithTime
         //where (i.UserInviterID == CurrentUserID) && i.MeetingStatus == true && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day) >= date
         select new ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp()
         {
             Name = i.UserInvited.FirstName + " " + i.UserInvited.LastName,
             //...
         };
```

Can I set this part to variable to use in all other extentions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to give up on the LINQ query syntax, and call the `Select` method directly. That should be no big deal. If you do that, you can store the projection part of your query in a separate variable.

```
Expression<Func<Meeting, ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp>> projection = i =>
    new ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp()
    {
        Name = i.UserInviter.FirstName + " " + i.UserInviter.LastName,
        Company = i.UserInviter.Company,
        Company2 = i.UserInvited.Company,
        MeetingID = i.MeetingID,
        Time = DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DbFunctions.AddHours(i.MeetingTime.Day, i.MeetingTime.Hour).Value, i.MeetingTime.Minute).Value,
        CreatedTime = i.dateCreated,
        Image = i.UserInviter.ProfileImage,
        TableNumber = i.TableNumber,
        Username = i.UserInviter.aspnet_User.UserName,
        Username2 = i.UserInvited.aspnet_User.UserName,
        UsernameInviter = i.UserInviter.aspnet_User.UserName,
        RequestText = i.RequestText,
        NoteInviter = i.NoteInviter,
        ResendInvitationCount = (i.ResendInvitationCount.HasValue) ? i.ResendInvitationCount.Value : 0,
        NoteInvited = i.NoteInvited,
        MeetingType = i.MeetingType.TypeName
    };

...

result =
   (from i in _dbContext.Meetings
    where i.UserInviterID == CurrentUserID
    && i.MeetingStatus == null
    && !i.IsTex
    && DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DbFunctions.AddHours(i.MeetingTime.Day, i.MeetingTime.Hour).Value, i.MeetingTime.Minute).Value > dateWithTime
    select i).Select(projection);
```

This keeps the entire part of the query server-side, exactly as if you had written it out in each query.

Comment: what will happens in call code? select all data and then modify it on EF side? SQL question will be like "select * from..." or not?

Comment: @OlegSh Run it and find out.  You should be looking at the generated SQL of most all LINQ queries you write when you're experimenting like this to verify that it comes out as it should.

Comment: @Servy I can understand the point of your edit, I know anything involving methods from classes in the `System.Linq` namespace is commonly called LINQ, but that doesn't make it correct, and that's not something I want to promote. :) LINQ *literally* means language-integrated query, and that's how I'm using it. I'm referring to "LINQ syntax" to stress the language-integrated aspect of it. Compare it to an explicit call to one of the `Select` extension methods, like my `.Select(projection)` at the end of my expression, which might still be reasonably called "query syntax", but not "LINQ syntax".

Comment: @hvd Well, your terminology is just that, your invented terminology.  It's not Microsoft's official terms for those concepts.  "query syntax" is the official name for the collection of keywords and syntax that you are using there.  LINQ is the collection of operators in the System.LINQ namespace.  The use of those methods, without query syntax, is still using LINQ.  Additionally, query syntax can be used to integrate with all sorts of other operations, besides just LINQ.  Given that that syntax doesn't even need to be used with LINQ, calling it LINQ syntax is simply incorrect.

Comment: @Servy It's used inconsistently by MS themselves. A quick Google search will bring up MSDN pages calling the syntax "LINQ syntax", "LINQ query syntax", "LINQ declarative query syntax", and indeed the "query syntax" you use. It's not just something I've made up.

Comment: I don't see any results for anything using the term "LINQ syntax".  Care to provide a link?  [The canonical page specifically about that exact language feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) specifically uses the term "Query Syntax" and "method syntax".  It's also very specific about referring to the usage of the method syntax as being LINQ, so it's very clear that LINQ is not referring to this particularly collection of keywords, but rather that they are an alternative tool by which one can write LINQ queries.  They are something LINQ uses, they are not LINQ.

Comment: @Servy Just looking for msdn "linq syntax", one result is ["PLINQ combines the simplicity and readability of LINQ syntax with the power of parallel programming."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And the [first page for LINQ I find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) starts as "Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) is a set of features introduced in Visual Studio 2008 that extends powerful query capabilities to the language syntax of C# and Visual Basic." (Again, it's used inconsistently by MS, so this doesn't invalidate what you found.)

Comment: @hvd The use of the term "LINQ Syntax" in that first link isn't referring to query syntax.  It's referring to the syntax of the LINQ operations, whether they're used in query syntax or not.  As for the second link, how is that inconstant with the view that these keywords make up query syntax, which is itself not called "LINQ syntax"?

Comment: @Servy About the first link: I can see why you think so, and I doubt there's anything that I can say that will convince you otherwise. Most other results I find make sense regardless of whether "LINQ syntax" can refer to what you might call "method syntax" too. About the second link: put in short, it says LINQ is a set of features that extends the language syntax. The new methods in the classees in the `System.Linq` namespace were added at the same time for obvious reasons, but don't extend the language, and can be used in a stripped down C# without LINQ syntax / query syntax.

Comment: @Servy The only thing I can find that definitely refers to the new syntax is [Unleash The Power Of Query In Visual Studio "Orcas"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163401.aspx), about VB.NET, but I'm not sure how official that terminology is. At any rate, let me see if I can edit my answer to something that is agreeable to both of us.

Comment: @hvd No, actually, they can't.  They rely extensively on new language features, such as the use of extension methods, method type inference, etc..  Other language features were added to help make LINQ an easy and effective tool.  The syntax you're referring to is one of them, but it itself isn't "what LINQ is".

Comment: @hvd I linked you to the page specifically discussing that syntax and what it is, and how it relates to LINQ.  Additionally, it's discussed in the C# language specs, which refer to it as query syntax and query expressions respectively.  That section of the specs doesn't even mention the term "LINQ".

Comment: @Servy Firstly, in my earlier comment, I didn't say they could be used without any of the new features of C# 3.0, I said they could be used without the new LINQ syntax / query syntax feature of C# 3.0. Secondly, while I certainly wouldn't recommend those methods to anyone dealing with a C# 2.0 compiler, I'm not convinced it's impossible, just highly impractical. Thirdly, this discussion is getting pointless. If I'm claiming that MS is being inconsistent, you finding pages where MS uses terms differently from how I am won't show me that MS isn't being inconsistent. Let's drop it.

Comment: You stated that adding LINQ required additions to the C# language, and if LINQ were just a collection of methods, it couldn't include those language features.  The fact remains that those methods wouldn't even compile in C# 2.0; they required certain language features (not query expressions) to even compile.  I'm showing you the canonical sources for referring to the specific language feature along with its *definition*; you're referring to, with the  exact terminology that they are referred to as.  You are only providing the use of your term in a single context of ambiguous intent.

Comment: @Servy No, I didn't state that. Please don't put words in my mouth. And again, can we drop this? There's no point in continuing.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can create a method that returns a `ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp` for you and call that method in the select.

Something like

```
private ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp MethodName(TypeOfI i)
{
   return new ITW2012Mobile.Core.DataTable.MeetingModel2Tmp() {
       //same stuff as in your question's initializer
   };
}
```

and call it with

```
    result = from i in _dbContext.Meetings
             where i.UserInvitedID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && //!i.IsTex &&
             DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DbFunctions.AddHours(i.MeetingTime.Day, i.MeetingTime.Hour).Value, i.MeetingTime.Minute).Value > dateWithTime
             //where i.UserInvitedID == CurrentUserID && i.MeetingStatus == null && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(i.AllowedTime.AllowedDate.Day) >= date
             select MethodName(i);
```

The query will get compiled down into LINQ extension methods anyway, and [`.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) takes in a `Func<TSource, TResult>` as an argument.  A [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is just a delegate (method) that has one input parameter (of type `TSource`) and returns a `TResult` object.

Comment: The name `_dbContext` strongly suggests that this is not LINQ to Objects, but rather LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities, and those use expression trees. When you're dealing with expression trees, you cannot easily factor out code into a separate method like that.

Comment: it does not work. Without any error. But does not go after call this expression (call .ToList() )

Comment: @OlegSh I'm guessing that this is LINQ-to-Sql?  If you had marked you question with this tag, or even just mentioned your data my answer would have changed.  I just assumed that this you wanted straight-up linq.

Comment: @ryanyuyu sorry, it's a linq-to-entities, my mistake